# Connect to Firebird database on Windows instance via CentOS

Tags: laravel, pdo, firebird

I have the task to establish a connection to a Firebird database that is located on a Windows instance. What I was able to accomplish so far was to establish a connection via PHP PDO on my local machine and query the databases.

However, I run into dead ends when I try to connect to the Firebird database that isn't on my PC locally. The database is located on a Windows remote server. The provider opened a port for that gets then redirected to port the Firebird database should be listening to as well (5143 was on my local machine and provider said it was the same on their end. So we try to connect over serveraddress:port and get forwarded to the corresponding port then).

First issue was to get Firebird working in CentOS but I got that down.
Connecting to the specified port I get the error *"SQLSTATE[HY000] [335544421] connection rejected by remote interface"*, any other, not open port, returns correctly *"connection refused"*.

Is it even possible to connect to a Windows remote server? Am I even "connected" / trying to connect to the Firebird database there and it gets declined then?

I read a lot about the rejected by remote interface error but nothing really pops into my mind what it can be.

I tried various setups, tried different ports, we logged on over TeamViewer and set up an ODBC connection locally on the remote desktop which succeeded. Both connections over the 32-bit and the 64-bit ODBC worked. We checked the Firebird versions and they were identical. We even tried to connect from a Windows notebook to the Windows remote.

I basically just want to establish a connection over PHP PDO.

Comment: There is no magic in Firebird, it uses ordinary TCP so wherever TCP work - Firebird can work as well. You can use ordinary tools for TCP connection diagnostic: netstat, nmap, tcpdump.

Comment: we tested with netcat to the specified port. It worked but I have no idea if it is directed further to the correct port on the client side

Comment: Please show the connection configuration you used. Some database tools and libraries use the format `<host>/<port>:<database>`, not `<host>:<port>/<database>`. For example, for [PDO Firebird](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.connection.php), the format is `firebird:dbname=hostname/port:/path/to/DATABASE.FDB`. Also check the firebird.log of the server. Also check the version of fbclient (libfbclient.so). The _"connection rejected by remote interface"_ can also occur if server side is Firebird 3.0 with WireCrypt=Required (the default) and client is a 2.5 or earlier.

Comment: In any case, this question is probably not suitable for Stack Overflow. I recommend asking on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel true. But I didnt even know that existed. thanks